# Disabling tabbar swiping over Tinder Like Cards UI

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I've 3 Tabs, built using `react-native-router-flux`.

I'm using `react-native-swiper-cards` to create a Tinder Like Card Swiping UI on the center tab.

But if the card is been tried to swipe with a "complete or almost close to horizontal gesture", then instead of the card been dragged, the tabs are getting swiped. In all other cases cards are been dragged without the tab getting swiped.

How to disable the Tab Swiping when cards are getting dragged totally horizontally?

Tabs.js

```
<Scene 
        {...navbarPropsTabs}
        key={'tabBar'} tabs={true}
        swipeEnabled={true}
        default="swipe">
        <Scene
            {...navbarPropsTabs}
            key={'settings'}
            component={SettingsScreen}
        ></Scene>
        <Scene
            {...navbarPropsTabs}
            key={'swipe'}
            component={SwipeScreen}
            initial
        ></Scene>
        <Scene
            {...navbarPropsTabs}
            key={'profile'}
            component={ProfileScreen}>
        </Scene>
```

Thats the code exact from the `react-native-swipe-cards` module.

```
this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (e, gestureState) => {
                if (Math.abs(gestureState.dx) > this.minDeltaThreshold || Math.abs(gestureState.dy) > this.minDeltaThreshold) {
                    this.props.onDragStart();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            },

            onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {
                this.state.pan.setOffset({ x: this.state.pan.x._value, y: this.state.pan.y._value });
                this.state.pan.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });
            },

            onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) => this.props.allowGestureTermination,

            onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
                null, { dx: this.state.pan.x, dy: this.props.dragY ? this.state.pan.y : 0 },
            ]),

            onPanResponderRelease: (e, {vx, vy, dx, dy}) => {
                this.props.onDragRelease()
                this.state.pan.flattenOffset();
                let velocity;
                if (Math.abs(dx) <= 5 && Math.abs(dy) <= 5)   //meaning the gesture did not cover any distance
                {
                    this.props.onClickHandler(this.state.card)
                }

                if (vx > 0) {
                    velocity = clamp(vx, 3, 5);
                } else if (vx < 0) {
                    velocity = clamp(vx * -1, 3, 5) * -1;
                } else {
                    velocity = dx < 0 ? -3 : 3;
                }

                const hasSwipedHorizontally = Math.abs(this.state.pan.x._value) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD
                const hasSwipedVertically = Math.abs(this.state.pan.y._value) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD
                if (hasSwipedHorizontally || (hasSwipedVertically && this.props.hasSwipeUpAction)) {

                    let cancelled = false;

                    const hasMovedRight = hasSwipedHorizontally && this.state.pan.x._value > 0
                    const hasMovedLeft = hasSwipedHorizontally && this.state.pan.x._value < 0
                    const hasMovedUp = hasSwipedVertically && this.state.pan.y._value < 0

                    if (hasMovedRight) {
                        cancelled = this.props.onSwipeRight(this.state.card);
                    } else if (hasMovedLeft) {
                        cancelled = this.props.onSwipeLeft(this.state.card);
                    } else if (hasMovedUp && this.props.hasSwipeUpAction) {
                        cancelled = this.props.onSwipeUp(this.state.card);
                    } else {
                        cancelled = true
                    }

                    //Yup or nope was cancelled, return the card to normal.
                    if (cancelled) {
                        this._resetPan();
                        return;
                    };
                    this.props.onCardRemoved(currentIndex[this.guid]);

                    if (this.props.smoothTransition) {
                        this._advanceState();
                    } else {
                        this.cardAnimation = Animated.decay(this.state.pan, {
                            velocity: { x: velocity, y: vy },
                            deceleration: 0.98
                        });
                        this.cardAnimation.start(status => {
                            if (status.finished) this._advanceState();
                            else this._resetState();

                            this.cardAnimation = null;
                        }
                        );
                    }

                } else {
                    this._resetPan();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I am assuming you want to preserve tab swiping in general, is that so?

Comment: Yes. Ofcourse. :)

Comment: Can you add the code from your router config? I need to see how tabs are configured

Comment: Also, try calling `Actions.refresh({ swipeEnabled: false })` in the beginning of the gesture and then `Actions.refresh({ swipeEnabled: true })`. This might work but it is a dirty hack

Comment: @AlexanderVitanov, Sorry for the delay. I've added the JS code for the tabs. Yes, its a hack, Should I put it inside 
`onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture` to make it work smoothly?

Comment: Also, any other proper solution to this?